# Kibana - what logs are not reporting

Tags: visualization, kibana-5

I am currently using kibana 5.0 almost 45 log sources are integrated with kibana like iis,vpn ,asa etc.now my question is how to create a visualization to check what logs sources are not reporting to kibana.can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution...
Make sure each log source is given a unique and meaningful tag as soon as their data enters the logstash workflow.
As each document is processed write an entry to a separate index, call it masterlist.idx (do not give this index a date suffix). Use the tags you assigned as the document ID when you write entries to masterlist.idx.

The masterlist.idx should really just contain a list of your log sources with each entry having a timestamp. Then all you've got to do is visualise masterlist showing all the entries. You should have 45 documents each with a timestamp showing their latest updates. I think the default timepicker on Kibana's discover tab will do the job. Any sources that haven't been updated in X days (or whenever your threshold is) have a problem.